# Using Monte Carlo to find a posterior probability distirbution (distirbution propagation)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, markov-process, posterior

Using Monte Carlo to propagate error is a well known technique. To do that, one usually uses the Markov equation to find the posterior distribution

$$
P(y|\mathbf{a})= \int  \delta(y-F(\zeta))P(\zeta | \mathbf{a})d \zeta, 
$$

where 
$$
y=F(\zeta)
$$

is our initial model, $P(\zeta|\mathbf{a})$ is the distribution of the input parameters $\mathbf{\zeta}$ given the inertial information available $\mathbf{a}$.

For an example consider the simple model 
$$
y=\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\frac{\zeta_3}{\zeta_4}\zeta_5^2.
$$
with Gaussian distributed, non-correlated parameters $\zeta_n$ with given $\sigma(\zeta_n),<\zeta_n>$.

In that case one just draws samples from multivariate Gaussian and evaluates the model $y=F(\mathbf{\zeta})$ which in our case is $y=\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\frac{\zeta_3}{\zeta_4}$. This procedure will finally yiled the distribution of my value of interest $y$.

What I don't understand is, how can I sample a different situation using the same model and $\zeta_n$. This time around I assume that my actual value should be zero, but due to the noise I will get a set of values distributed around the zero. i.e. I will still get some values, besides the given the initial condition that $y=0$ .
This meas that I still have a set of input values $\zeta_n$ but this time I am not really sure what my model should be. Should I use $y=0$ or $\zeta_1+\zeta_2+\frac{\zeta_3}{\zeta_4}\zeta_5^2=0$, where the last would mean that one of the variables is cyclic. 
I would appreciate your help and ideas.